# Database of colors mapped to species

Tags: literature, database, species, color

I was wondering about the [physics of color](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483106/database-of-color-emissions), and now am interested in finding out if there are any resources (databases, text files, html tables, or pdf listings) of species and their associated colors or (ideally) color wavelength spectrum.

For example, a rose bush might have a pink (flower) color spectrum and a green (leaf) and brown (stem) color spectrum. A worm might have a brown and pink color spectrum. A lion might have a yellow and brown and gold color spectrum. Wondering (a) if any of this information is captured in any form on the web (such as 1 journal article per species), and (b) if it is aggregated into a database, text file, table, or other sort of list which includes lots of species (animals, plants, fungi, rocks, etc.), so it would say the wavelength of visible light that it emits, or some ranges of it, or even a hex color range.

Comment: would be unbelievably difficult as not only do many species have multiple colors in a single individual  or change color over time but many species also vary in color from individual to individual, then you have the species that cn voluntarily change color. You might be able to find a database of pigments but not one of colors.

Comment: Pigments would work too.

Comment: I have rose bushes with flower colors ranging from white through dark yellow, pale pink to a very dark red, and a couple of rather lavender-ish ones - and that's just in my own garden.  Then there are the multi-hued flowers of e.g. iris, particularly aril iris: https://www.google.com/search?complete=0&q=aril+iris&tbm=isch&source=hp&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwionsub3sPiAhUpJzQIHaZ9DGYQsAR6BAgHEAE&biw=1311&bih=946

Comment: FYI there is a very simple and clear answer to this in regards to minerals - https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17081/database-of-color-wavelengths-of-minerals